# Python on Spider (Python 3.11.4 64-bit | Qt 5.15.2 | PyQt5 5.15.7 | Darwin 22.3.0) is running also commented code

Tags: python, kernel

I'm running the code below, and there is something very strange to me. If I run only line 1, line 2, and line 3, I get the array 'centr' with all zeros except for the first row, which contains different numbers (line 3).

Then I uncomment lines 4 and 5, and I get 'centr' populated with other numbers, which, until now, is what I was expecting.

But then, if I delete the variable from the workspace and run only lines 1 to 3, I get unexpected numbers for the array 'centr', as if the compiler is also running lines 4 and 5. Every time I run the code (up to Line 3) I got different value form centr.

```
#%% Open libraries and data

import pickle
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
#from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
import random



## Open data

with open('random_multinormal.pkl', 'rb') as file:
    M = pickle.load(file)


#%% Setup initial centroids

# Line 1
K = round(M.shape[0]/5) #number of centroids

# Line 2
centr = np.empty((K,2))

# Line 3
centr[0] = M[random.randint(0, M.shape[0]-1)]

# Line 4
p_centr = np.linalg.norm(M - centr[1], axis=1)**2/np.sum(np.linalg.norm(M - centr[1])**2)

# Line 5
centr[1:]= M[np.random.choice(np.arange(0, M.shape[0]), size=K-1, replace=False, p=p_centr)]
```

Every time I run the code (up to Line 3) I got different value form centr.
If I restart the kernel everything is ok, but the error came up again if I follow the procedure described above.